# tails from cumulant generating function

Tags: distributions, moment-generating-function, characteristic-function

I am trying to obtain finite-sample tail estimates using the mgf. I found a snippet in a google books preview of a formula giving the survivor function by some kind of inversion of the cumulant generating function. I would appreciate any other references (hopefully openly accessible, but any authors/keywords would help). According to an exercise in "Intermediate Probability: A Computational Approach" by Marc S. Paolella,

$$
1-F_X(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\exp(\mathbb{K}_X(s)-sx)/s ds
$$
for $c>0$ in the convergence strip of the cumulant generating function $\mathbb{K_X}$. Also what is the notation on the limits of integration; a line through $c$ parallel to the imaginary axis? So that $s$ is imaginary?

I'm not looking for a proof (an outline is given in the google books preview) as much as references to related theory, examples, or applications. Possibly this formula is considered such a modest extension of fourier inversion that it isn't discussed at any length.

Comment: This integral inverts the Laplace transform.  It is a complex contour integral.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the integration variable $s$ goes along a line through $c$ parallel to the imaginary axis. Write $s=c+iy$, where $y\in R$,
$$\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}f(s)ds = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(c+iy)\mathrm{d}(c+iy)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(c+iy)i\mathrm{d}y$$

Find a textbook about complex function or complex analysis if you want to go further and understand this formula.